# VBA Error with Ubound when referring to 1 cell

Tags: arrays, vba

I´m trying to understand the arrays in VBA, but I´m struggling a little bit, particularly with these lines. I can´t understand why, when the range I´m referring to is one or two cells, I get a mismatch error type 13 with the UBound.

```
Dim var2 As Variant
sArray2() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim range2 As Range

lastrow = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("P" & _ 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set range2 = Workbooks(Umsatzdatenbank).Sheets("Filter").Range("P3:P" & _ 
lastrow)
var2 = range2.Value
ReDim sArray2(1 To UBound(var2))
For i = 1 To (UBound(var2))
sArray2(i) = var2(i, 1)
Next
```

Comment: If  UBound(var2)) is 1 , sArray2(1 to 1).  It is not  array.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the value of a single cell to a variable, the variable will be a single value, not an array. That's how Excel/VBA works, you cannot change this.

You can check if your variable `var2` (not the best name for a variable IMHO), is an array or not and react to it, for example like:

```
var2 = range2.Value
If IsArray(var2) Then
    ReDim sArray2(1 To UBound(var2))
    For i = 1 To (UBound(var2))
        sArray2(i) = var2(i, 1)
    Next
Else
    ReDim sArray2(1 To 1)
    sArray2(1) = var2
End If
```